# Send SMTP email from different email to smtp server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have set up an actionmailer for a basic contact form that send the email via my gmail address.

At the moment when I send an email, the from address, is my gmail address, whereas I would like it to be the email address entered into the contact form.

mail(to: "testemail@gmail.com", from: @email, subject: "Test Subject")

I couldn't find any answers for this, so how do I go about achieving this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that anymore. Unless the email address exists and is authorized to send email from gmail servers (credentials required) you will not be able to use random `FROM` address.

Even if you are successful in sending an email like that from your own mail relay server, the email will almost always get marked as spam. There are several checks done on an email, such as:

- DKIM Signing
- SPF records
- Reverse DNS check

Hence, it is not advisable to use a `FROM` address entered on a web form. It will spoil the reputation of your IP address. That may result in your genuine emails also getting trapped by spam filters.

Comment: Is it possible to set a different reply to address, to the same effect?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, you can, although I noticed hitting the reply button on gmail does not default to reply-to but the from field. is there anyway my users can easily reply to a contct form submission without having to manually copy/paste or enter the reply to email address.

Comment: There are third party plugins available. Either those that directly hook into gmail, or the ones you run on your server. Look from `CRM` plugins. I can suggest you to have a look at VTiger CRM. It allows you to hook up a web form with its lead tracking module. Your users can use the CRM provided interfaces to interact with customers. I am sure several other CMR tools have similar functionality.

Comment: I found that sendmail was able to do it